# Custom color State map of factors in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to figure out if it is better to use breaks within ggplot or create them before. My issue is trying to create custom colors with this. I would like to use a purple scale. I can get it to look great without the breaks, but California and Texas dominate in that case

Since I cannot attach a file: This is content of statd for statepop.csv

```
> statd
   Rank          State Population  X
1     1     California   38802500 NA
2     2          Texas   26956958 NA
3     3        Florida   19893297 NA
4     4       New York   19746227 NA
5     5       Illinois   12880580 NA
6     6   Pennsylvania   12787209 NA
7     7           Ohio   11594163 NA
8     8        Georgia   10097343 NA
9     9 North Carolina    9943964 NA
10   10       Michigan    9909877 NA
11   11     New Jersey    8938175 NA
12   12       Virginia    8326289 NA
13   13     Washington    7061530 NA
14   14  Massachusetts    6745408 NA
15   15        Arizona    6731484 NA
16   16        Indiana    6596855 NA
17   17      Tennessee    6549352 NA
18   18       Missouri    6063589 NA
19   19       Maryland    5976407 NA
20   20      Wisconsin    5757564 NA
21   21      Minnesota    5457173 NA
22   22       Colorado    5355856 NA
23   23        Alabama    4849377 NA
24   24 South Carolina    4832482 NA
25   25      Louisiana    4649676 NA
26   26       Kentucky    4413457 NA
27   27         Oregon    3970239 NA
28   28       Oklahoma    3878051 NA
29   29    Connecticut    3596677 NA
30   30           Iowa    3107126 NA
31   31       Arkansas    2994079 NA
32   32    Mississippi    2984926 NA
33   33           Utah    2942902 NA
34   34         Kansas    2904021 NA
35   35         Nevada    2839099 NA
36   36     New Mexico    2085572 NA
37   37       Nebraska    1881503 NA
38   38  West Virginia    1850326 NA
39   39          Idaho    1634464 NA
40   40         Hawaii    1419561 NA
41   41          Maine    1330089 NA
42   42  New Hampshire    1326813 NA
43   43   Rhode Island    1055173 NA
44   44        Montana    1023579 NA
45   45       Delaware     935614 NA
46   46   South Dakota     853175 NA
47   47   North Dakota     739482 NA
48   48         Alaska     737732 NA
49   49        Vermont     626011 NA
50   50        Wyoming     584153 NA
```

This is code below

```
library(readxl)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)   # devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2") only if you want subtitles/captions
library(ggalt)
library(ggthemes)
library(albersusa) # devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/albersusa")
library(viridis)
library(scales)

statd<-read.csv('C:/statepop.csv')
us <- usa_composite()
us_map <- fortify(us, region="name")

# I may make a version of this that returns a fortified data.frame but
# for now, we just need to read the built-in saved shapefile and turn it
# into something ggplot2 can handle

statd$Population <- cut(statd$Population,breaks=6)
colors <- brewer.pal(6, "Purples") #set breaks for the 9 

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=us_map, map=us_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.1, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + theme_map()

gg + coord_map()
gg + 
  geom_map(data=statd, map=us_map,
           aes(fill=Population, map_id=State),
           color="black", size=0.1) +
  coord_proj(us_laea_proj) +
  theme(legend.position="right") + labs(title="U.S. Population")
```

Comment: Does your question have anything to do with `rstudio`? Please consider removing this tag.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you now know how to set custom breaks with `cut`? See `?cut`. Or do you not know how to use a continuous purple scale? `+scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Purples")`. Or do want to transform your scale? `scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Purples", trans = "log")`. Or are you unhappy that CA and TX dwarf the population of other states? You might need some nukes or an earthquake machine... and it's off-topic; see supervillains.stackexchange.

Comment: Also, you could probably simplify your code to make it more minimal, are you using half of the packages you load in this example?